# Read a file in a shell script

Tags: shell

I want to read a file in a shell script with comparing to a given user data

Ex:-

file: vm_list.txt having following data

```
vm1,vm2,vm3
```

user given as parameter vm2,vm4

First it will read vm_list.txt file and compare user given parameters vm2,vm4.
If it's a valid vm give output as valid if not this vm does not exist or given wrong vm name.

I tried below logic but I'm not able to achieve the correct result.

code:

```
for vm_name in "${vm_names[@]}"
do
  VM_LIST_FILE="/tmp/$AZ_ACCOUNT.vm.list"
  az vm list --output table > "$VM_LIST_FILE"
  vm_rg_name=$(grep $vm_name "${VM_LIST_FILE}" |
               awk '{ print $2 }' | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')
  if cat $VM_LIST_FILE | grep '$vm_name'; then
     echo "This vm $vm_name is Present on $vm_rg_name"
  else
     echo "This vm $vm_name is not present or invalid vm Name"
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 1):

One problem is the single quoting in

```
cat $VM_LIST_FILE | grep '$vm_name'
```

This will not substitute $vm_name. You need to use double quotes:

```
grep "$vm_name" $VM_LIST_FILE
```

and save a useless cat on the way.

Besides from this, `grep|awk` is an anti-pattern, because awk can do the grepping: `awk '/pattern/ { action }'` is what should be used instead.